# Fourier Transform of $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin x\sin nx}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to find the Fourier transform of $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin x\sin nx}{x^2}$ and have not been successful yet. I am wondering if there is an easy way of solving the following integral. $$\hat f_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x\sin nx}{x^2}e^{-ixt}dx$$

I tried writing $e^{-ixt}=\cos(xt)-i\sin(xt)$ and got the following ;$$\hat f_n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x\sin (nx)\cos(xt)}{x^2}dx-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x\sin (nx)\sin(xt)}{x^2}dx}_{=0\text{ by symmetry}}$$

How can I proceed from here?

Comment: Do you mean to have $dx$?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes! Fixed it

Comment: you may want to note to start that the product of three odd functions over an even function is odd so the first integral is what you need to worry about (assuming convergence is clear)

Comment: @qbert so the imaginary part of the integral is 0. Thanks for the tip. Any tips for the real part?

Comment: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin+x%5Csin+%28nx%29%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D , but do not ask me how to do it.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $\text{sinc}(x)$ is well-known and the Fourier trasform of a product is related to a convolution of Fourier transforms.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The Fourier transform of a convolution is the product of the transforms. That I know. I just don't see how it relates to this yet

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio can you integrate the first guy using residues (and deviating the usual contour to avoid 0)?

Comment: @brucesmitherson this can be achieved by splitting the sines into $\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ and $\frac1{2i}(e^{inx}-e^{-inx})$, then using the fact that $F\left[\frac{e^{ikx}}{x^2}\right]=-\sqrt{\frac\pi2}(k+t)\text{sgn} (k+t)$.

Comment: @Heisenberg: compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Compute the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}$. Compute the convolution of these Fourier transforms and you are done: the graph of $\widehat{f}_n(x)$ is an isosceles trapezoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(1x)\sin(nx)\cos(tx)}{x^2}\,dx\\=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)\left[\sin((n+t)x)+\sin((n-t)x)\right]}{x^2}\,dx\\=\Large\scriptstyle{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos((1-n-t)x)-\cos((1+n+t)x)+\cos((1-n+t)x)-\cos((1+n-t)x)}{x^2}\,dx} $$
and by integration by parts
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1-\cos(\alpha x)}{x^2}\,dx = \pi|\alpha|$$
hence the graph of $\widehat{f_n}(t)$ is an isosceles trapezoid: this also follows from the fact that $\widehat{f_n}(t)$ (up to a multiplicative constant) is given by the convolution of the characteristic functions of two intervals.